# The inner part of the left rear tire is covered with oil

Tags: brakes, tires, troubleshooting, golf, leak

[image]

[image]

[image]

The car VW Golf IV  was parked in the same spot overnight, this morning I see the inner part of the tire with oil.

Anyone have similar problems?
Any help is welcome

edit: it is not oil but brake fluid, I am driving it tomorrow morning on low speed to a mechanic 10 km away

edit 2: mechanic will replace the whole "cylinder" with a used part from another graveyard car, the whole thing will cost 1/6 of my monthly income ( in the 3rd world country I live in ), hopefully this new part lasts longer

Comment: Oil? Or brake fluid?

Comment: Clean, fresh brake fluid would be clear and it has a distinctive smell. If the fluid was contaminated (perhaps just by dirt from the tire) it could be black. What led you to notice it?

Comment: If it has cv axles in the rear, it could be a broken outer cv boot.

Comment: A 10km drive with no brakes is going to be a harrowing and potentially dangerous experience. Most likely, a few more pumps on your brake pedal and you'll blow out the rest of the fluid and lose them completely. If you really can't get it towed, please be careful. Practice stopping the vehicle with the parking brake and the transmission first, get an idea of how long it takes you to stop; be *extremely* cautious on downhill areas or areas with pedestrians and traffic.

Comment: I dont get any cred for suspecting brake fluid right at the start :\

Comment: @StevenRichardOakes Nope. If you want the glory, you gotta type in the answer box, lol.

Comment: I missed the updated photos and someone beat me to it. Get that sh*t repaired bro.

Comment: I have seen this exact problem before, it is brake fluid leaking out of the handbrake mechanism.  You will need to replace the calliper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't an oil source that I can think of by the rear tires of a Mk4 Golf, as pointed out in the comments a brake fluid leak seems much more likely. Brake fluid is normally clear, but it could be dark with contamination or you could be picking up road dirt and grease from the tire. Brake fluid is a very good solvent, so it may also be carrying dirt and grease from the hub.

A brake fluid leak is serious, so this is worth investigating further.

Brake fluid has a distinctive smell and feel, so you might be able to identify it that way. Check the brake fluid reservoir in the engine compartment, both for quantity of fluid and to learn what it smells like. I think it would be ok to dip a clean finger into the fluid to learn what it feels like.

Also look at the rear wheel and find the small metal pipes and rubber hoses that run from the wheels. Those carry the brake fluid, follow them to the wheel and look around where they connect (on the brake caliper) for any signs of leaks on both sides of the rotor (the disc that the brakes grab to stop the wheel). I fear that you'll find the source there and that means either learning how to repair the brakes or taking the car in for repair.

Comment: Also I would be really, *really* cautious if you choose to drive this car. If you have to move it any appreciable distance to fix it you really ought to have it towed.

Answer (score 4):

As others have commented - there aren't engine oil lines or a reservoir that contains engine oil near the rear of the car so you can almost rule out your own engine oil as the source. To verify, you could open your hood and check your engine oil level.

It could be your brake line that runs into the caliper. Brake lines usually alternate between lengths of rubber tubing and steel tubing. Most cars have a rubber line that connects with a small metal elbow piece at the brake caliper. This elbow is generally a fragile piece - not in quality but the piece carries a lot of stress and the tube itself is a diameter of ~8mm.

Depending on many things, primarily age, your tubing might be brittle and caused a leak. Other issues could be elbow junction.

**Definitely do not drive your car until you verify a few things.**

Check your brake oil level in your engine bay; Usually a small container connected to the firewall of your car. Another option, turn your car on while in park, and slowly press your brake pedal. If you have a leak, you should feel less pressure under your foot than normal and also, you'd see a lot more oil near the rear tire.